# MongoDB Add new field to each element of array

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a mongo collection `myCollection` with the following structure :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxx"),
  "name" : "name1",
  "address" : "address1",
  "list" : [
      { "field1" : true,
        "field2" : false
      },
      { "field1" : true,
        "field2" : false
      }]
},
...
,
{ "_id" : ObjectId("zzzzzzzzz"),
  "name" : "name100",
  "address" : "address100",
  "list" : [
      { "field1" : true,
        "field2" : false
      },
      { "field1" : true,
        "field2" : true
      }]
}
```

For each document of the collection, I would like to create a new field (`field3`) with the default value false for each subelement of the array `list`.

Expected output :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxx"),
  "name" : "name1",
  "address" : "address1",
  "list" : [
      { "field1" : true,
        "field2" : false,
        "field3" : false
      },
      { "field1" : true,
        "field2" : false,
        "field3" : false
      }]
},
...
,
{ "_id" : ObjectId("zzzzzzzzz"),
  "name" : "name100",
  "address" : "address100",
  "list" : [
      { "field1" : true,
        "field2" : false,
        "field3" : false
      },
      { "field1" : true,
        "field2" : true,
        "field3" : false
      }]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried update with `$map`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$addFields` to add more fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "list.fields3": false
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LaEHyYAIhV3)**